# How do I get a meaninful exception from a dynamically emitted assembly?

Tags: reflection, f#

Trying to debug emit errors, is there a simple way to find out more information about exceptions c
caused by emitted code?

For example, with this code:

```
let dynamicAssembly =
    let asmName = new AssemblyName("MyAsm")
    let asmBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(asmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run)
    let moduleBuilder = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MyModule")
    let typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("MyDynamicType")
    let methodBuilder = 
        let build = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("MyMethod", MethodAttributes.Public, 
                                                CallingConventions.Standard,
                                                typeof<Int32>,
                                                [|typeof<Int32>; typeof<Int32>|])
        let ilGen = build.GetILGenerator()
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0)
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1)
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Add)
        ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)

    typeBuilder.CreateType() |> ignore
    asmBuilder

let myType = dynamicAssembly.GetType("MyDynamicType")
let myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType)
myObj.GetType().GetMethod("MyMethod").Invoke(myObj, [|2; 3|])  |> ignore
```

I get "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation., when I try to call `Invoke` on the second to last line. Emitting code has always been problematic, but it might be less painful if I could figure out how to get meaningful exceptions. Thoughts?

Comment: What is the inner exception of the exception that you've caught?

Comment: That would be cool, except there isn't one

Comment: Oh, I've been proven wrong. Thanks for the suggestion. For some reason the editor didn't show an inner exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting useless exceptions is a part of the joy of generating IL code. When you get "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation", you can look at the `InnerException` property and see if you can get something more useful there:

```
try
  myObj.GetType().GetMethod("MyMethod").Invoke(myObj, [|2; 3|])  |> printfn "%A"
with 
  e -> printfn "%A" e.InnerException
```

In this case, the inner exception says:

> System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

This simply means that your generated IL is wrong - I'm afraid you won't get a better error message, but you can save the generated assembly to a disk and run `peverify` or Reflector/ILSpy to see how they would interpret the generated code. This means you'll need to add another code path to generate a proper (non-dynamic) assembly, but I think it is worth it - you'll need to debug the generated IL often...

In this case, the problem is that `Ldarg_0` refers to `this` (rather than the first argument) and so you need to generate:

```
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1)
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_2)
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Add)
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret)
```

Comment: gah, yes I knew it had to do with that. So when do I use ldArg_0?

Comment: Awesome, I'm up and running again!

Comment: @TomasPetricek Quality answer, as always!

Comment: @sircodesalot I think you would need `Ldarg_0` if you were generating an instance method and you wanted to call `this.Foo(...)`. In that case, `Ldarg_0` puts the `this` reference on the stack.